# Regex pattern for URL string

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to find regex pattern for url and use `regex.test()` so only string like this:

```
http://*.margonem.pl/
```

so it's exactly like above string and where `*` must appear and can be string which only contains `a-z` letters without any signs.

Comment: Either `^http://(?:[a-z]+\.)?margonem\.pl/$` or `^http:\/\/(?:[a-z]+\.)?margonem\.pl\/$` (depending on the usage).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That would be [`http:\/\/[a-z]+\.margonem\.pl\/`](https://regex101.com/r/xl5eAG/1):

## Matches

```
http://a.margonem.pl/
http://foo.margonem.pl/
```

## Does not match

```
http://hello-world.margonem.pl/
http://abcq443435u4531.margonem.pl/
```

Comment: @dopeCode Why not? `www` can be a subdomain.

Comment: Sorry nevermind